# can angular6 elements have routing?

Tags: angular6

With V6, the angular team has introduced angular elements which is good for micro frontends.

However, can they be fully-fledged applications with routing and everything else that a complex angular application might have?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the router in Angular Elements, however there is an open Github issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23740
which also features an example which might help you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elements-routing

Answer (score 1):

no yet, it is too soon to apply everything we use in angular 6, I am using https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa for the time being. Angular is not ready yet.